# Where is Visual C++ Redistributable Installer in VS 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Professional installed. I have built a C++ application and I want to install the redistributable runtime on another machine. Is the installer available in VS installation? Or do I have to [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a5c84275-3b97-4ab7-a40d-3802b2af5fc2) it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look in %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\ for the platform(s) you require.

Comment: Let that be "%ProgramFiles%" (without the space).

Comment: At least I didn't assume it was on the c: volume :)

Comment: No problem -- did tweak for completeness, for when the next person needs to find it, as it isn't the most obvious location